# Looking to protect OSB through the winter

Tags: waterproofing, plywood

I've been building a small cabin in the mountains for the past year or so in my spare time and finally have a sub floor laid out and screwed down. I have no time frame as to when I get a roof over the floor and with winter approaching, I'd like to get something to protect my OSB from the elements.

I am in southern california and we're supposed to have a wet winter. Not necessarily snow, but a lot of rain. I know the OSB comes presealed, but I'd like to add another layer of protection.

I was thinking something like deck sealer or this patio paint from HD: http://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-Premium-1-Gal-PFC-35-Rich-Brown-Low-Lustre-Porch-and-Patio-Floor-Paint-630001/203939583

I spent $100 dollars on a thick, large tarp that lasted a couple months, but the wind destroyed it. It gets pretty windy up there. Below is a picture of the subfloor I have finished. It is about 320sqft.

I understand, I can't completely waterproof this stuff, but I want to try and at least get it through this winter season.

[image]

Comment: How is it attached? Your best bet may just be to pull it up and store it.

Comment: @Drew It is just screwed down, but I'd like to not work backwards if don't have to. If I can throw a coating on it, I'd rather do that. Removing it is certainly an option if nothing will protect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prime and paint is your best option.  Exterior paint will create a thin latex layer of protection over the surface.  Use primer first to be sure and get a good bond with the somewhat-presealed OSB, then two coats of a quality exterior (porch paint should be great) paint.  Two gallons of paint and two gallons of primer should be plenty for two coats.  And remember that a coat of primer and a coat of paint is better than two coats of paint.

Be sure and and get very good coverage on the edges.  I might go so far as to caulk the seams with some cheap caulking to prevent water from soaking to the cracks.

Comment: I was just talking to my friend about caulking the perimeter actually so rainwater doesn't run under the floor when it hits the tyvek. Ok so primer and an exterior latex paint. How well would that hold up to walking on it? I am guessing it would start to peel if too much foot traffic was on it. What about a rubberized roof coating?

Comment: If you plan on finishing the cabin in a year or so, just paint should be fine, and you can always put another coat on high traffic areas if it looks like its wearing down, but "porch paint" is made for that.  I'd be worried that a roof coating would be too thick and may start to be a hassle when putting up walls and the finished flooring.  And to be clear, I'd caulk the perimeter and all the joints - just use the basic cheap caulking.

Comment: Ok great! I'll stay away from roof coating thing. From what I read it's more of a rubberized coating. I'm guessing I'll have a roof over it within a year and putting another layer on the higher traffic areas shouldn't be a problem. I will definitely do the primer first. All the joints have been caulked actually. It is just the perimeter that hasn't You can see the caulking on the joints in my photos

Comment: do you think a primer/paint combo would be a bad idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I believe in the paint primer combos yet...  I'd do separate since the extra layers building up will help.  I'd use a combo if going over a previously finished surface.  Also, if you don't mind working with it, use an oil based primer.  You can then cover with a latex paint.

Comment: ok, I just know I want to get it done this weekend and only have 1/2 day to be up there. From what I read it looks like I can do two coats of primer in about 1.5 hours and then around hour 2, throw on the latex paint. Why do you recommend an oil based primer over latex? The minimal amount of searching is showing me people not liking to use it because of the smell. I haven't found why it is better to use one or the other.

Comment: Oil base bonds better and covers better, in general. Since you're outside and don't have to clean brushes, the downsides don't apply. But, a water based primer might dry faster (not sure, check) and still do a great job.

Comment: rad, thank you! I think I will stick to just the water based. Sounds easier and is more common